# Nice Inequality

Tags: inequality

I'm solving this inequality trying to use some changes of variable (for example $u=\frac{bc}{a}$, $v=\frac{ac}{b}$, $w=\frac{ab}{c}$), but I couldn't simplify the expression.

The inequality is: For $a,b,c>0$ such that $\frac{1}{a}+\frac{1}{b}+\frac{1}{c}=1$, show that $$\left(1+\frac{bc}{a}\right)\left(1+\frac{ac}{b}\right)\left(1+\frac{ab}{c}\right)\ge\frac{64}{81}(a+b+c)^2$$

Do you have any hint?

Thanks in advanced.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't know if this can help you:

$$\left(1+\frac{bc}{a}\right)\left(1+\frac{ac}{b}\right)\left(1+\frac{ab}{c}\right)\\
=\left(\frac{(a+bc)(b+ac)(c+ab)}{abc}\right)\\
=\left(\frac{(a+abc-ac-ab)(b+abc-bc-ab)(c+abc-bc-ac)}{abc}\right)\\
=(1+bc-c-b)(1+ac-c-a)(1+ab-b-a)\\
=(1-a)^2(1-b)^2(1-c)^2$$

Comment: Excellent!! With your observation is very easy to finish

Comment: +1. It reduces to prove $a+b+c \ge 9$, which is easy using $\frac{1}{a}+\frac{1}{b}+\frac{1}{c} \ge \frac{9}{a+b+c}$.